# How to redirect HTTP POST request in flutter?

Tags: flutter, http, post, redirect, dio

I'm using a local payment gateway API [PayFast](https://developers.payfast.co.za/docs#quickstart).

This is the HTML sandbox implementation that works fine:

```
<form action="https://sandbox.payfast.co.za​/eng/process" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="10000100">
   <input type="hidden" name="merchant_key" value="46f0cd694581a">
   <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Product">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I'm trying to achieve the same outcome on Flutter using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio). This is what I have thus far:

```
var formData = FormData.fromMap({
                    'merchant_key': '46f0cd694581a',
                    'merchant_id': '10000100',
                    'amount': '123.45',
                    'item_name': '#BP000123',
                  });
var response = await Dio().post(
                    "https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process",
                    data: formData,
 );
```

The problem is response does not redirect to the payment page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you share if you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: @com_run Yes see my dirty solution below:

Answer (score 0):

This is my messy solution and in no ways the cleanest method. That being said it works.

This is the "confirm" button" when you want to redirect the user to the payfast page:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

  return OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        // Navigate to Payfast redirect:
        //Map
        Map map = {
          'merchant_id': '10xxxx00',
          'merchant_key': '46xxxxx1a',
          'return_url': 'https://www.google.com/search?q=success',
          'amount':  99999,
          'item_name': 'This is drugs',
          "name_first": 'user .name',
          'name_last': user.surname,
          'email_address': user.email,
          'cell_number': user.number,
        };
        String concatString = '';
        map.forEach((key, value) {
          concatString = '$concatString$key=$value&';
        });
        //Remove last "&":
        concatString = concatString.substring(0, concatString.length - 1);
        // Add the passphrase:
        // concatString = '${concatString}passphrase=jt7NxxxFZPn';
        // URL encoded:
        String urlEncoded = Uri.encodeComponent(concatString);
        // Replace .replace(/%20/g, "+")
        urlEncoded = urlEncoded.replaceAll('%20', "+");
        // Create MD5 signature:
        var md5 = crypto.md5;
        // UTF* encode:
        List<int> encoded = utf8.encode(urlEncoded);
        // base64:
        var newBase64 = base64.encode(md5.convert(encoded).bytes);
        // Add the signature to the map:
        map.putIfAbsent('signature', () => newBase64);
        // Convert Map to Json object:
        js.JsObject obj = js.JsObject.jsify(map);
        // Call JS function:
        js.context.callMethod('callPayfast', [obj]);
      },
      child: const Text('Proceed'),
    );
```

In your web/index.html file add this in the bottom of the body, it is important to maintain the order of the key values:

```
// For Payfast: 
    var down = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN");

    // Create a break line element
    var br = document.createElement("br");

    function callPayfast(obj) {
      // console.log(md5("test"))
      // Create a form dynamically
      var form = document.createElement("form");
      form.setAttribute("method", "post");
      form.setAttribute("action", "https://sandbox.payfast.co.za​/eng/process");


      // Merchant ID:  <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="10000100">
      var merchID = document.createElement("input");
      merchID.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      merchID.setAttribute("name", "merchant_id");

      merchID.setAttribute("value", obj["merchant_id"]);


      // <input type="hidden" name="merchant_key" value="46f0cd694581a">
      var merchKey = document.createElement("input");
      merchKey.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      merchKey.setAttribute("name", "merchant_key");
      merchKey.setAttribute("value", obj["merchant_key"]);

      // <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100.00">
      var amount = document.createElement("input");
      amount.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      amount.setAttribute("name", "amount");
      amount.setAttribute("value", obj["amount"]);

      // <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Product">
      var itemName = document.createElement("input");
      itemName.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      itemName.setAttribute("name", "item_name");
      itemName.setAttribute("value", obj["item_name"]);

      // <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="https://www.google.com/search?q=success">
      var return_url = document.createElement("input");
      return_url.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      return_url.setAttribute("value", obj["return_url"]);
      return_url.setAttribute("name", "return_url");

      // <input type="hidden" name="name_first" value="John">
      var name_first = document.createElement("input");
      name_first.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      name_first.setAttribute("name", "name_first");
      name_first.setAttribute("value", obj["name_first"]);
      // <input type="hidden" name="name_last" value="Doe">
      var name_last = document.createElement("input");
      name_last.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      name_last.setAttribute("name", "name_last");
      name_last.setAttribute("value", obj["name_last"]);
      // <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="john@doe.com">
      var email_address = document.createElement("input");
      email_address.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      email_address.setAttribute("name", "email_address");
      email_address.setAttribute("value", obj["email_address"]);
      // <input type="hidden" name="cell_number" value="0823456789"> 
      var cell_number = document.createElement("input");
      cell_number.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      cell_number.setAttribute("name", "cell_number");
      cell_number.setAttribute("value", obj["cell_number"]);
      // <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="f103e22c0418655fb03991538c51bfd5"> 
      var md5Element = document.createElement("input");
      md5Element.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      md5Element.setAttribute("name", "signature");
      md5Element.setAttribute("value", obj["signature"]);


      // create a submit button
      var submit = document.createElement("input");
      submit.setAttribute("type", "submit");
      submit.setAttribute("value", "Submit");
      submit.setAttribute("id", "submit312100");


      // Append the merch id: 
      form.appendChild(merchID);
      // Appen merch key: 
      form.appendChild(merchKey);
      // Appen return url: 
      form.append(return_url);
      // Append Amount:
      form.append(amount);
      // Append Item name: 
      form.append(itemName);
      //name_first
      form.append(name_first);
      // name_last
      form.append(name_last);
      // email_address
      form.append(email_address);
      // cell_number
      form.append(cell_number);
      // signature
      form.append(md5);
      // Append the submit button to the form
      form.appendChild(submit);

      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
        .appendChild(form);

      // CLick on the button: 
      document.getElementById('submit312100').click();
    }
```